# AWS RDS SSL - Does ssl server certificates different for each and every RDS instance or same?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I have 2 aws accounts having their own RDS instances(not publicly accessible) with db engine as postgresql 12.5. I downloaded RDS certificate from "https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem".
I am using JDBC(postgresql driver) with properties ssl=true and sslrootcert="path to above certificate" to establish secure connections.
My questions:

1. This certificate is same for both aws accounts which have different names, so how does it work , Does ssl hand shake verifies that client(jdbc connection) is talking to rds.amazonaws.com or the actual RDS instance which has separate name ?
2. RDS certificates are replaced every 5 years, i.e. applications also have to update the certificate every 5 years or sooner than that once new certificate is available from RDS, is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1.

Yes, its same for all accounts. You can download it from docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html). Its about the instances as explained in the docs:

> Using a server certificate provides an extra layer of security by **validating** that the connection is being made to an **Amazon RDS DB instance**.

Q2.

You can update before actual expiration few months before. Last year it happened as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-rds-customers-update-your-ssl-tls-certificates-by-february-5-2020/):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The server's certificates are each different.  Each server sends its own cert when you ask to establish a SSL connection to it.  The thing you download is the cert for the authority which *signs* each of the server certs.  You (Or your JDBC) use it to verify that the per-server certs are genuine.